# How to create a X509Certificate2 with the the CA, client cert and the client key?

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate2

I am trying to run the gRPC default project that is created in visual studio. I choose the gRPC ASP template.

I am trying to use self-signed certificates to connect to the service.

When I use grpui to connect, I have to specify the CA certificate, the client certificate and the client key to connect. I need to specify the CA certificate to verify the server certificate because it is a self-signed certificate.

Then I want to connect from a WPF application where I need to create a X509Certificate2 object.

The way I know how to create is this:

```
var cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(paramCertificado, paramKey);
```

but when I try to connect, I get an error that tells that the client closed the connection. I can see this message in the log of the service, when the client try to call to a method in the service.

How I can connect from grpcui when I specify the CA certificate? I tried to connect with grpcui without specifying the CA certificate. Then I get this error: "certificate signed by unknown authority".

So I am sure that I have to create the X509Certificate2 by specifying the CA certificate, but I don't know how to create this kind of certificates using the CA certificate and the client certificates.

Thanks.

Comment: "self-signed" and "CA" are mutually exclusive.  There's nothing fancy you need to do (or can do) when creating the `X509Certificate2` instance, you need to get your certificate from an issuer the other computer trusts (or make it trust your self-signed certificate).

Comment: Then why with grpcui with the same certificates if I indicate the CA I can connect and if I don't indicate I get an error? Also in some past tries with native gprc, using Grpc.Core, I could use new KeyCertificatePair(_clientCertificate, _clientPrivateKey) and then use new SslCredentials(_caCertificate, keypair) to indicate the CA and then I could use it to create the channel new Channel(_serviceAddress, _port, sslCreds). In this way I could set the CA. But with Grpc.Net I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @bartonjs How could trust my slef.signed cetificate? My idea it is to have a library for the gRPC service, that get the string of the ca cert and client certificates. I this way I could use this library from a MAUI project, an WPF application another clients. If I don't misunderstand, trust self-signed certificate means to add it to the certificates store in windows? If this is the solution, how could apply it in my MAUI project?